# LuaSQLite - reading a single entry

Tags: sqlite, lua

I would like to read a single entry from sqlite-database with [LuaSQLite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/index) and not all rows.

```
local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")

local db = sqlite3.open_memory()

db:exec[[
  CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content);

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello World');
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Lua');
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Sqlite3')
]]

for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
  print(row.id, row.content)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your query to "SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1" and it will just return a single row. Retaining the 'for' loop is the simplest way to get at that row; the 'do' block will only be executed once.